# The canvas covers the metrowindow title

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have a project that is a picture view, which allows the user to drag the picture in window, but there's a problem to this.

When the picture in a canvas was dragged to the top, it covers the title. I don't know how to solve this issue, please help!!!

```
namespace OfficeStyleWindowProject
{

  public partial class Window1 : MetroWindow
  {
    public Window1()
    {
    }
    Point LastPos;
    private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //移动画布
        Point curr_pos = e.GetPosition(this);
        Canvas grid = sender as Canvas;

        if ((e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed))
        {
            Matrix m = grid.RenderTransform.Value;
            m.Translate(curr_pos.X - LastPos.X, curr_pos.Y - LastPos.Y);
            grid.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(m);

        }

        LastPos = curr_pos;
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        LastPos = e.GetPosition(this);
    }
  }
}


<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="OfficeStyleWindowProject.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    
    xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    Title="Office Style Window" 
    Height="300" 
    Width="300" Panel.ZIndex="1000"
    WindowTitleBrush="Green">

    <Canvas Width="200" Height="200" 
        Background="Red"  
        MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove" 
        MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown">

    </Canvas>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

[program started,and no drag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjuQN.jpg)

[It's the problem, canvas covers the window title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz9Iz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the position of the mouse or rectangle and check where on the window is. If the position will be at bad place, do not rerender the canvas.

```
Point LastPos;
private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point curr_pos = e.GetPosition(this);
    Canvas grid = sender as Canvas;

    if ((e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed))
    {
        double top = grid.GetTop();
        var diffY = curr_pos.Y - LastPos.Y;

        //If new position of canvas will be smaller then title bar size, do not transform.
        if((top + diffY) < 26)
            return;

        Matrix m = grid.RenderTransform.Value;
        m.Translate(curr_pos.X - LastPos.X, curr_pos.Y - LastPos.Y);
        grid.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(m);

    }

    LastPos = curr_pos;
}
```